# Can not update photo into a database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

the code save the photo inside the folder in root, but in the database not save the rute into the photo...can you help me with this.

here the form:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <fieldset>
            <legend><i class='icon32 icon-wrench'></i>Configuración General del Sistema</legend>

            <div class='control-group'>
                <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Nombre de la Clínica</label>
                <div class='controls'>
                    <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='nombre_clinica' 
                        value='<?php echo $nombre_clinica;  ?>' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='control-group'>
                <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Dirección</label>
                <div class='controls'>
                    <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='direccion' 
                        value='<?php echo $direccion;  ?>' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='control-group'>
                <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Número de Teléfono</label>
                <div class='controls'>
                    <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='telefono_clinica' 
                        value='<?php echo $telefono_clinica; ?>' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='control-group'>
                <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Viñeta de página web</label>
                <div class='controls'>
                    <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='titulo_clinica' 
                        value='<?php echo $titulo_clinica; ?>' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='control-group'>
                <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Logo Clínica</label>
                <div class='controls'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" /> <input data-clear-btn="true" class="input-file uniform_on" name="logo" id="fileInput" value="nopic.jpg" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"/> 
                    <br />
                    <img style='max-height:80px;' src='../images/<?php echo $logo; ?>' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='control-group'>
                <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Meta tag del Software clínico</label>
                <div class='controls'>
                    <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='page_meta_tag' 
                        value='<?php echo $page_meta_tag; ?>' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='control-group'>
                <div class='controls'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id ?>' /><input type='hidden' name='action' value='update' />
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Actualizar configuracion' />
                </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
         </form>
```

and here is the code:

```
    <?php
include '../include/update_config.php';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if($action == "update"){
        try{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], "../images/" . $_FILES['logo']['name']);
             $query = 'update CONFIGURACION set id = :id, nombre_clinica = :nombre_clinica, direccion = :direccion, telefono_clinica = :telefono_clinica, titulo_clinica = :titulo_clinica, logo = :logo, page_meta_tag = :page_meta_tag where id = 0';
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

                $stmt->bindParam(':nombre_clinica', $_POST['nombre_clinica']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':direccion', $_POST['direccion']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':telefono_clinica', $_POST['telefono_clinica']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_clinica', $_POST['titulo_clinica']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':logo', $_POST['logo']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':page_meta_tag', $_POST['page_meta_tag']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);

                // Execute the query
                $stmt->execute();

                echo "Registro actualizado correctamente.";

        }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
                echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
}

try {

        $query = "select nombre_clinica, direccion, telefono_clinica, titulo_clinica, logo, page_meta_tag from CONFIGURACION where id = 0";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['id']);

        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $id = $row['id'];
        $nombre_clinica = $row['nombre_clinica'];
        $direccion = $row['direccion'];
        $telefono_clinica = $row['telefono_clinica'];
        $titulo_clinica = $row['titulo_clinica'];
        $logo = $row['logo'];
        $page_meta_tag = $row['page_meta_tag'];


}catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}


?>
```

the photo is save succesfully in the folder ../images/

Comment: Why `where id = 0`?  I think that is your problem.

Comment: as @leftclickben noted, shouldn't it be `$query = "select ... where id = ?";` as you are doing `$stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['id']);`

Comment: @asterix_jv what is the value you are getting now in the column `logo`

Comment: hi,  @leftclickben and @Sean even with `id = ?";` the pdo not save me the rute to the photo, but save it in the folder

Comment: hi, @Deonia the value when the user dont want upload a photo is `value="nopic.jpg"` is inside of form

Comment: @asterix_jv which is the colum for image path in update query?

Comment: @Deonia this is the path `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], "../images/" . $_FILES['logo']['name']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = "images/" . $_FILES['logo']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], "../".$path);
...
$stmt->bindParam(':logo', $path);
```

Comment: @asterix_jv, It's also completely insecure!  I can just upload whatever file I want to your server.  You aren't checking the path or anything.  What if I upload `something-evil.php` and run it from my browser?  Never keep user-uploaded documents in the doc root.  Never let the user specify the file name as it is on your disk.

Comment: @Brad them I need to sanitize?? I am not know much PDO... can you give me a clue?

Comment: @asterix_jv this is what I was about to tell you to do . You were not setting the path to logo image

Comment: @asterix_jv, No this has nothing to do with PDO, but where you are moving files to on disk.

Comment: @Deonia and @Brad so I need to put the entire path to the folder?, like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/soft/images/';` and checking the extension with this : `function isImage($type) {
    static $imageTypes = array(
            'image/gif'=>1, 'image/jpeg'=>1, 'image/pjpeg'=>1, 'image/png'=>1,
        );
    return isset($imageTypes[$type]);
    /* OR */
    return preg_match('%^image/(?:p?jpeg|gif|png)%', $type);
    /* OR allow all images */
    return preg_match('%^image/%', $type);
}` ??

Comment: You might want to ignore the user created name and give it a random file name with the right extension.

What they mean is that you should put the file in /user-uploaded-images so that the user does not have the opportunity to upload a file that will *replace* your executable php code.